# Can you dereference an integer literal?

Tags: c++, pointers

Is it possible to use, for example:

```
int x = *776
```

to get a value from a specific memory location? Or do you absolutely have to use:

```
int ref = 776;
int x = *ref;
```

Comment: `int x = *((int*)776)`. Congrats, you may have found one of the quickest ways to segfault!

Comment: Does `776` address a specific memory address? Or what do you mean?

Comment: Because of some of the abstractions used in modern computers (ie. virtual memory), dereferencing an integer literal may not mean what you think it means, and will usually segfault.

Comment: Can you guarantee that you are accessing physical memory? Or is your system using segmented memory accessing or relative memory accessing?

Comment: `int x = *ref;` does not compile

Comment: Gents: There's a world outside x86, Linux and Windows - On a micro controller, this (the second one, provided you add some proper casts) is a useful construct (assuming the memory location exists and means something to someone). And: It is definitely allowed by the language. Not so the first one: There is no way to express a pointer literal other than NULL in C.

Comment: Unless you are programming for an embedded system and know exactly to what 776 is mapped, you do not want to do this.

Comment: @tofro the second one doesn't work. Compiler will not allow you to dereference an `int`. Some casting (see CompuChip above and πάντα ῥεῖ below) is required.

Comment: If you were on a micro controller and referencing a known address in ROM, then I would think that it would be better to write the code like so: `myType *pTheVal = (myType *)776` instead of just `myType theVal = *(776)`, even if the compiler did allow the latter.

Comment: Please note that any time you want to point to memory at a specific physical location, you probably want to avoid having those memory accesses optimized away.  Therefore, use `(volatile int*)` and not just `(int*)`

Comment: @tofro `NULL` is an integer literal (possibly cast to pointer type), but not a pointer literal in either case

Comment: @M.M Some implementations of C++ define `NULL` as `nullptr` which is of type `nullptr_t` and is not necessarily an integer literal.

Comment: @callyalater I was responding to tofro's comment which was talking about C  (maybe he overlooked that this was a C++ question)

Comment: After taking a c programming class and learning how pointers actually work this is kind of an embarrassing question. I was so naive then, I didn't even know what there was to learn...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, memory addresses can be expressed from certain integer literals, such as

```
int* ptr = reinterpret_cast<int*>(776);
```

and dereferencing these as

```
int value = *ptr;
```

is legit. So is

```
int value = *reinterpret_cast<int*>(776);
```

If you can actually access this hard coded memory address totally depends on your target environment.

In most cases the operating system will prevent you from accessing arbitrary memory addresses and quit you with a `SEGFAULT` or alike.

---

> Or do you absolutely have to use:
>
> ```
> int ref = 776;
> int x = *ref;
> ```

You cannot use that code, that's completely nonsensical and won't compile.

What you probably meant was

```
int* ref = reinterpret_cast<int*>(776);
int x = *ref;
```

and as mentioned above

```
int x = *reinterpret_cast<int*>(776);
```

is legit as well.

Comment: "*is legit.*" If your definition of "legit" includes "undefined behavior", then sure.

Comment: @NicolBolas Casting doesn't imply _undefined behavior_ inherently as long you are know what you're doing. How does your washing machine work?

Comment: `int* ref = 776;` won't compile, but `int* ref = (int*)776;` does.

Comment: @callyalater Fixed that.

Comment: It might be appropriate to mention that if you absolutely need this, use `int x = *reinterpret_cast<int*>(776);`. That _intentionally_ sticks out like a sore thumb.

Comment: This question is reminding me of the [Fast Inverse Square Root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root#Overview_of_the_code) bit hack that was done in casting a `float` to a `long` and other weird things.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: "*Casting doesn't imply undefined behavior inherently as long you are know what you're doing.*" It is undefined behavior to take an arbitrary literal number, pretend its a pointer, and then dereference it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Do you mind changing `SEGFAULT` to `SIGSEGV` or "segmentation fault"? I don't think that `SEGFAULT` is an error code.

Answer (score 2):

In short, no. You cannot say `int x = *776;` because `776` is an integer literal and interpreted as an `int` not an `int*`.

The longer answer is that you (probably) don't want to do this (the concept of explicitly dereferencing a specific memory address) because (1) it is not portable, (2) makes your code very fragile, and (3) doesn't really do what you want it to do.

There are many way to [access memory on a computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addressing_mode), but they are not mutually compatible. The most basic way is called direct addressing. This is where each place in memory has an address and when you say "Go to location 0x308" it goes to that cell in physical memory. This can be very dangerous because you can access regions of memory that the OS or BIOS is using. It also prevents you from (easily) running more than one program on your computer.

Other ways of indirect accessing memory is relative (offset) addressing and segmented addressing. These have a layer of protection between the addresses you are using and the physical layout and can prevent you from accessing memory you are not supposed to. Generally speaking, this is why you get segfaults.

If you write code that is accessing memory at a specific location, the OS may screw everything up for you, or you could break your microcontroller.

So though you could do `int x = *((int*)776);`, you probably don't *want* to do that and it will most likely segfault.

Comment: Interesting: I know of no microcontroller that can be "broken" by reading from an address.

Comment: I killed my MSP 430 by writing bad code. (The magic smoke escaped.)